# How to quickly and repeatedly copy a 16x28 range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, database, copy

I have a lot of spaced-out data in Excel that I want to be copied into another workbook.  I'm having to drag and copy ALOT, like hundreds of times.  This is obviously slow and tedious. (it's a baseball player database, so I have to do this for every player, not just one time).

The data isn't in a column-string, it's a 16x28 array so, like B1908:Q1935.  **Can I set a "template" range like 28x16 to be highlighted from a cell I click in?**  I'm copying the data into a calculator of sorts and want to speed up the highlighting of data that I'm copying.

I do have a macros-button set up to copy the output of the calculator, that won't work here (?) as I have 16x28 arrays in hundreds of different places, rather than one like my calculator.  I want to move the player cards back into the calculator quickly...
[image: trying to auto-copy ranges like this]
Thank you!

Comment: The range you're looking for is e.g. `Selection.Cells(1).Resize(28, 16)`. `Cells(1)` is used if you accidentally select more cells. It's not clear what you're planning to do with it. Please do clarify and share the codes you've already got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a macro that selects a 16x28 range from the currently selected cell, which you could then assign to a keyboard shortcut. I have tested and the below works:

```
Sub selectRange16x28()
Dim lastCellRow As Long: lastCellRow = ActiveCell.Row + 15 '+27 if you want 28 rows
Dim lastCellColumn As Long: lastCellColumn = ActiveCell.Column + 27 '+15 if you want 16 columns

ActiveCell.Worksheet.range(ActiveCell, Cells(lastCellRow, lastCellColumn)).Copy
End Sub
```

So now put that code into your Personal Workbook and assign it to a keyboard shortcut by pressing ALT+F8, then select the macro, click options, and assign a keyboard shortcut. Then you'll just have to click on the cell you want to start copying from, press the short-cut, and it's copied.